# Birthday Card on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, gifts

Is there any prohibition against giving a birthday card, (no present) written out before Shabbat to a person on Shabbat?

Comment: Will it be carried through a public domain without an eiruv (by either party)?

Comment: [Edit]ing in your motivation for asking (e.g. why do you add "(no present)"?) may help others address your concerns.

Comment: please explain why you think a birthday card is not a present

Comment: @Menachem Maybe its value (after being written) is less than a prutah? That would probably mean that there is no kinyan (acqusition) which would be a problem with a present of value.

Comment: Sam, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Please note the comments above on how you could make your question more answerable, and note that anything you learn here should be treated as potentially useful, but [not authoritative](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi) information. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.